# How to share a ViewModel between custom Views of different Fragments?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I have an Activity which contains 2 Fragments which contains various custom Views each.

How can I share a ViewModel between theses custom Views?

-Fragments-

```
private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

-Custom Views-

```
private val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()!!).get<MainViewModel>()
}
```

The problem is that **findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()** returns the Fragment instead of the Activity, creating a new ViewModel instead of sharing the existing one.

Is there any way to share an Activity ViewModel between the custom Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner()` in your Custom view returns Fragment instead of Activity since your View have attached to Fragment and therefore this method returns Fragment.

You can try to explicitly cast `Activity` of your `View` to `ViewModelStoreOwner` and get a `ViewModel` from `ViewModelProvider` created with this Activity. Then, `ViewModel` of your Activity has to be returned (Kotlin would do automatic type cast Activity to ViewModelStoreOwner, but just for clarity):

```
// Your Activity:
private val mainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

// Your custom views:
private val mainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(activity as ViewModelStoreOwner).get<MainViewModel>()
}
```